# How to run external commands in C application built with MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, system, createprocess

I've an application written in `C`, which has to run under `Windows`, and built with `MinGW`.

In this application I have to run a bash command and I've tried both `CreateProcess()` and `system()` functions.

In both cases, the command I pass works fine if I launch the application through the `MinGW` console, but not if I run it double-clicking.

So my question is: if I run it through the `MinGW` console, the command is executed by the `MinGW` console, but if I run it double-clicking, where does it try to execute the command?

Comment: *What* "command" are you trying to run? Are you using a relative path to the program? Then when you double-click on your program to start it, the working directory of the process (from which relative paths are relative to) will very likely not be what you expect. Have you tried using an absolute path to the program you want to run?

Comment: I have to run `git` and do some stuff like `git clone`, `git pull` and so on.
The point is that I'm proceeding exactly as I did for other commands, like `convert`.
I imported both `convert` and `git` into my `MinGW`. When I create the application bundle, `covert.exe` and `git.exe` are placed in the bundle `bin/` folder, as the application runner.
`convert` command always works, `git` command doesn't (with double-click opening).

Comment: Does `git` run if you try to start it from `cmd` instead of the MinGW console? Presumably your environment variable PATH does *not* include the path to the Git executable.

Comment: `git` doesn't run from `cmd`, but also `convert` doesn't.